# How to use BitmapShader without repeat

Tags: java, android, canvas, graphics

I want to create a heart shape drown on screen when user touches the smartphone screen(working on a drawing android app). So i setup the BitmapShader as below code

```
//Initialize the bitmap object by loading an image from the resources folder
Bitmap fillBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.heart);
fillBMP = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fillBMP, 20, 20, false);                
//Initialize the BitmapShader with the Bitmap object and set the texture tile mode
shader= new BitmapShader(fillBMP, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

Then i assign the shader paint object.

```
paint.setShader(preset.shader);
```

I have also setup the touch listener to track the user finger. On user touch i draw this on canvas object as.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(mid1.x, mid1.y);
path.quadTo(midmid.x, midmid.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

This give me this

[image]

Where some heart shape are croped and also these are repeated. What i want not these are repeated and never croped like this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really like this question because of how the hearts in your example are also rotated in regard to the slope of the curve they're on. I doubt there's anything built in to android which can achieve this out of the box. If no-one answers your question soon, I will attempt to build a project which does exactly this, upload it to github and link it here with a brief explanation. Nice question.

Comment: @Max can you please share with us your final code, I have followed the accepted answer, but I want to use the finger to draw on the canvas

Comment: @GilMoshayof can you look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65740714/14988618

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a bit of trouble uploading to Git, so for now, I'll post the solution here.

Here's a helper class I wrote to create the effect you want. I added comments in-line to explain what I'm doing.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PathMeasure;

// Use this class with a Canvas to create the effect you want.
public class CurvedBitmapDrawer
{
    private Context mContext;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private int mResourceId;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Path mPath;
    private int mBitmapMargin;

    // Create with a context so that this class can use resource ids.
    public CurvedBitmapDrawer(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    // getters setters for paint.
    // this paint will be used to draw the bitmaps, and the strokeWidth value in the paint
    // will be used to set the thickness of the curve / line that is drawn.
    public Paint getPaint() {
        return mPaint;
    }

    public void setPaint(Paint paint) {
        mPaint = paint;
    }

    // getters setters for the space between the bitmaps.
    public int getBitmapMargin()
    {
        return mBitmapMargin;
    }

    public void setBitmapMargin(int bitmapMargin)
    {
        mBitmapMargin = bitmapMargin;
    }

    // getters setters for res id
    public int getResourceId() {
        return mResourceId;
    }

    public void setResourceId(int resourceId)
    {
        mResourceId = resourceId;
        mBitmap = null;
    }

    // alternative optional getters setters for bitmap.
    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        return mBitmap;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mResourceId = 0;
    }

    // I decided to only use a local path here, but feel free to change it.
    // call getPath to perform actions on the path that is drawn by this class.
    public Path getPath()
    {
        return mPath;
    }

    // draw method. comments inline.
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // grab a bitmap in the desired size.
        final Bitmap scaledBitmap = getScaledBitmap();

        // find the center of the bitmap.
        final float centerX = scaledBitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        final float centerY = scaledBitmap.getHeight() / 2;

        // wrap the path with a measurement tool for paths - PathMeasure
        final PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(mPath, false);

        // initialize the distance to the center of the bitmap.
        float distance = scaledBitmap.getWidth() / 2;

        // initialize position and slope buffers.
        float[] position = new float[2];
        float[] slope = new float[2];

        float slopeDegree;

        // draw so long as the distance traveled on the path isn't longer than
        // the total distance of the path.
        while (distance < pathMeasure.getLength())
        {
            // grab the position & slope (tangent) on a particular distance along the path.
            pathMeasure.getPosTan(distance, position, slope);

            // convert the vector to a degree.
            slopeDegree = (float)((Math.atan2(slope[1], slope[0]) * 180f) / Math.PI);

            // preserve the current state of the canvas
            canvas.save();

            // translate the canvas to the position on the path.
            canvas.translate(position[0] - centerX, position[1] - centerY);

            // rotate the canvas around the center of the bitmap the amount of degrees needed.
            canvas.rotate(slopeDegree, centerX, centerY);

            // draw the bitmap
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);

            // revert the bitmap to the previous state
            canvas.restore();

            // increase the distance by the bitmap's width + the desired margin.
            distance += scaledBitmap.getWidth() + mBitmapMargin;
        }

    }

    // returns a scaled bitmap from the asset specified.
    private Bitmap getScaledBitmap()
    {
        // no bitmap or resId, return null (no special handing of this! add if you like).
        if (mBitmap == null && mResourceId == 0)
            return null;

        // if no bitmap is specified, create one from the resource id. 
        // Optimization: be sure to clear the bitmap once done.
        if (mBitmap == null)
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mResourceId);

        // width / height of the bitmap[
        float width = mBitmap.getWidth();
        float height = mBitmap.getHeight();

        // ratio of the bitmap
        float ratio = width / height;

        // set the height of the bitmap to the width of the path (from the paint object).
        float scaledHeight = mPaint.getStrokeWidth();

        // to maintain aspect ratio of the bitmap, use the height * ratio for the width.
        float scaledWidth = scaledHeight * ratio;

        // return the generated bitmap, scaled to the correct size.
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, (int)scaledWidth, (int)scaledHeight, true);
    }
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

        CurvedBitmapDrawer drawer = new CurvedBitmapDrawer(this);

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setStrokeWidth(50);

        drawer.setPaint(paint);
        drawer.setResourceId(R.drawable.heart_icon);
        drawer.setBitmapMargin(10);

        Path path = drawer.getPath();

        path.moveTo(80, 90);
        path.cubicTo(160, 470, 750, 290, 440, 880);

        Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(finalBitmap);

        drawer.draw(canvas);

        image.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);
```

I've tested it here and it seems to work well, minus some edge cases perhaps. Here's what it looks like with the given usage example:

[image: Hearts Along A Curve]

Remember to set the stroke width on the paint object you supply, or else nothing will be drawn (and probably will cause an exception with the current code).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This worked perfectly with fix path. But i want to draw this with user finger. Can you please help me, how to use this with touch listener. I am using this example to draw the line. When i try that with this anotationview this works very slow.
https://github.com/khankuan/AndroidBezierFreehand

Comment: Please also help me to change this bitmap color dynamically.

Comment: Just update the path as the user moves his finger and redraw.

Comment: If you'd like to know how to adjust a Path via touch events, or how to change the color of a bitmap, I suggest you look up how to do this and if you can't find a way, feel free to ask a separate question here on stack overflow. If you link it to me, I'll attempt to answer it too. Please do not alter your question to tailor to your specific requirements.

Comment: Ok, I will ask new question for changing color of bitmap. But this question was draw heart shape with user finger touch. I will try to fix the path issue or I will ask new question for both. Still this will help me thanks.